# Would it make sense to translate a city to latitude=0 longitude=0 before doing any calculations?

Tags: coordinate-system

I'm working on a conversion system for Unity. We want to import some geo-referenced data (not models) losing the least floating point resolution possible.
I am currently working on the idea of moving all the data as we import it right to the equator across the Greenwich line, in other words to the geodetic origin.
Basically we take the commonly accepted center of that town and translate it.
This would simplify the conversion to cartesian space and assure that we can stay within acceptable bounds for floating point resolution (usually ±10000).
Does this all make sense?

Comment: The Earth is an oblate spheroid. Using a local projection is going to be more accurate than shifting the latitude. If your coordinates are single precision, use double  precision; If they're double precision you've already got more precision than accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title, no.

As Vince points out in the comments, the Earth is not a perfect sphere, so distance and area calculations will be not be correct if your city does not lie on the equator.

Comment: So what if in my model I am allowed to consider the Earth a perfect sphere? Would it make sense then?

Comment: I think there's a better way to achieve what you are after. What are your limits? For lat/longs, you only need 3 digits for the whole number, and 6 (maybe 7) digits for the remainder.